# Suppose $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent. Show that the cross product of $v$ and $w$ is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Suppose $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent. Show that the cross product of $v$ and $w$ is linearly independent.**

I understand how to calculate the cross product of two linearly independent vectors and have found that the result is linearly independent. I don't understand how to construct a abstract proof to represent all cases and answer the question.

Cheers

Comment: What is the cross product of v and w supposed to be linearly independent to?

Comment: I am not sure, the question did not say.

Comment: I am being mostly annoying.  The question is probably asking to show that  $ \{v , w, and v \times w \}$ form a linearly independent set. The way your question is stated does not make sense however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that the cross product $v\times w$ is orthogonal to $v$ and $w$. Since $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent, this implies that the three vectors are linearly independent. Indeed suppose that
$$
c_1v+c_2w+c_3(v\times w)=0\tag{0}
$$
for some $c_i$. Then take the inner product with respect to $v\times w$ of both sides to yield that
$$
c_3|v\times w|^2=0
$$
so $c_3=0$ (since $v\neq 0$ and $w\neq 0$). Hence $(0)$ becomes
$$
c_1v+c_2w=0.
$$
But $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent so $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$ as desired.

Comment: Im sorry, don't quite understand how you take the inner product with respect to v x w, and, then cancel c1v + c2w.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $ w, v, w \times v$ were linearly dependent.  Then there exists scalars a and b such that $$ aw + bv = w \times v $$

“Dot producting” both sides of this equation with $w \times v$ gives $0$ on one side and a positive number on the other.

Answer (score 0):

One can define the cross product of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ to be a vector perpendicular to both $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, with the *right hand rule* used to determine the direction,  and magnitude equal to the area of the parallelogram spanned by $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, that is, $\mid \vec a\mid\mid \vec b\mid\sin\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between them.

If we use this definition then we are done right away.

According to Wikipedia,  the equivalency with the determinant definition is not that easy.

Answer (score 0):

When vector a and b are orthogonal then

$a.b = 0$, and a and b are linearly independent, i.e. $a+b \ne 0$.

Now v and w are linearly independent so $k_1v+k_2w \ne 0$, we take the dot product of this non zero vector with the cross product of v,w say u.

$u.(k_1v+k_2w) = k_1u.v+k_2u.w$, now as u is orthogonal to v and w we have
$u.(k_1v+k_2w) = k_1u.v+k_2u.w = 0 + 0 = 0$

So $u+(k_1v+k_2w)\ne 0$, which is equivalent to $k_3u+k_1v+k_2w\ne 0$

(because if $k_3u+k_1v+k_2w= 0$ then assuming $k_3$ is non zero, $u+(k_1/k_3)v+(k_2/k_3)w= 0$ )

that indicates $u,v,w$ are linearly independent.